# How to get newly typed text in react-native text input?

Tags: javascript, text, react-native, onchange, textinput

When user types text in `TextInput`, `onChangeText` and `onChange` are called.

- I am getting `event` from `onChange` callback and can get newly updated text from `event.nativeEvent.text`.
- I am getting `text` from `onChangeText` callback and can get newly updated text from it.

But I only want newly entered text/letters. How to get this?

For example:-
lets assume we have `som` as text in `TextInput`, now as soon as user type `e`, I want only this **`e`** instead of whole text `some`.

Any work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get newly typed letters via

Use `onSelectionChange` props in your `Input`. We can get an `event` from `onSelectionChange` from which we can get `cursor` position. Through `cursor` position and full text we can easily get **newly entered letters**.

Example:-

```
      <Input
        ...
        onChangeText={this.handleMessageChange}
        onSelectionChange={this.handleMessageSelectionChange}
        ...
      />
```

And methods

```
handleMessageChange = (message: string) => {
    this.setState({ message });
  };

handleMessageSelectionChange = (event: Object) => {
    const { selection } = event.nativeEvent;
    this.setState({ selection });
  };
```

Now whenever you want newly entered letters, get it

```
getNewlyEnteredLetters = (): string => {
        const { selection, message } = state;
        const { start, end } = selection;
        return start === end ? message[start -1 ] : message[message.length - 1] 
      }; // start === end implies that new letters are entered and not selection is made.
```

Answer (score 0):

To get only the newly entered text you can use the **onChange** function of TextInput as below:-

```
 <TextInput  
    onChange={(event) => {console.log(event.nativeEvent.data)}}
    onChangeText={(val) => {console.warn(val)}}
 />
```

As specified the onChangeText will give you the complete text but you can use the event from onChange to get the newly eneterd letter.

**EDIT**

According to your react native newer versions you get the complete new text in **event.nativeEvent.text** and no data in **event.nativeEvent.data**. So for your requirement you can use the code below for now :-

```
                <TextInput 
                onChange={(evnt)=>{
                        let newText = [];
                        let oldText = [];

                    for(let i=0;i<evnt.nativeEvent.text.length;i++) {
                        newText.push(evnt.nativeEvent.text[i]);
                        if(this.state.val[i]) {
                            oldText.push(this.state.val[i]);                                
                        }
                    }
                    let newLetter = '';
                    for(let j=0;j<newText.length;j++) {
                        if(newText[j] !== oldText[j]) {
                            newLetter = newText[j];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    console.log(newLetter);
                }}
                onChangeText={(val)=>{
                    console.log(val);
                    this.setState({val});
                }}
            />
```

You will get the newly entered letter inside your console of **newLetter**. I will let you know if i find anything else related to this but for now you can get working with this :)

Comment: first of I am getting undefined on using `event.nativeEvent.data`, it is working if it is changed to `event.nativeEvent.text`. And second one is I am getting whole text from `event.nativeEvent.text`. I am on v0.47.1 of react-native

Comment: @VishweshJainkuniya i have updated the answer above and you can get your desired output by this :)

Comment: Thanks got another approach via `onSelectionChange`.

Answer (score -1):

One way to solve this in pure js try this with the string

```
getNewChar(str){
  return str[str.length - 1];
}
```

Comment: It is not sure that user will always enter at last.

Comment: Thanks got another approach via `onSelectionChange`